# Identification High Leverage for Logistic Regression

Tags: r, logistic, generalized-linear-model, leverage, rule-of-thumb

As seen below from Piet De Jong, Generalized Linear Models for Insurance Data, for linear model, we can identify high leverage, if the value of leverage>2p/n (or hii > 2p/n) then the indicates the case is unusual in the space of explanatory variables.

[image]

[image]

If I have a Logit Regression/Logistic Regression, does anyone know can I use the rule of thumb that $h_{ii}>2p/n$ to identify large leverage? Or does anyone have references for the rule of thumb for $h_{ii}$ (to identify which case is unusual in the space of explanatory variable) in logistic regression?

Comment: Relevant (not a duplicate):  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81058/how-to-handle-leverage-values

Comment: Is your goal to identify the influential observations/outliers for the model? The diagnostic tools are less informative for logistic regression, because it is harder for an individual observation to have a great impact (unlike linear regression).

Comment: However, you may still use something like cook distance that measures the standardized change in the linear predictor of your logistic model, when the ith case is deleted.

Comment: But I am not sure if the rule of thumb for leverage in the linear regression setting is still applicable here, although you can also get such leverage value from the linear predictor of your logistic model